# kotlin data class with annotations, why @DateTimeFormat annotation works without targetting

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

```
data class UserSearchRequest(
        @field:NotNull
        val active: Boolean?,
        // no targeting work
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) 
        @field:NotNull
        val registeredDate: LocalDate,
)
```

why `@DateTimeFormat` annotation works without targetting?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by targetting.  The @DateTimeFormat references `registeredDate` because it is the next field so it has a target.

Comment: @Neil targetting i mean putting '@field:' or '@get', which referring https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

Comment: in kotlin data class if you dont specify target on annotation, it will be added into constructor not on field itself so annotation won't be worked just like @NotNull won't work isnt it

Answer (score 0):

you registered kotlin module, it allows you to apply jackson annotations to constructor params without targeting but it doesn't work for java validation like your NotNull annotations